# System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. On production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am writing following code to make my application hit another internal page:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    String DummyPageUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/Maintenance.aspx";
    client.DownloadData(DummyPageUrl);
```

It works fine on staging server but the same code gives "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." error on production server which is on client's end. However when I rewrote the code as below, it worked there:

```
String DummyPageUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/Maintenance.aspx";
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(DummyPageUrl);
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

But the issue is that I am using Pechking dll for converting another page in the application to pdf. So when I supplied the url of the page to the dll, it also gave the same error. Now if I get the html content myself using second method like above and supply to Pechkin dll, I get into formatting issue in generated pdf. So, as a matter of fact, I just want the server to allow the code to send request for a requested page in the application.
I have also checked IIS settings on the server. For example, Anonymous authentication is enabled there. I have set Managed Pipeline Mode there in application pool as 'Classic' like we have on staging server. But nothing seems to work. I think we are still missing some settings there.
Please help.